# How to use Active Record counter cache with the all scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an activerecord class method scope that returns `all` when the scope should remain unchanged. However I would expect it to use the counter cache when chaining `size` to the `all` scope. Here is an example:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true

  def self.filtered(only_approved:)
    if only_approved
      where(approved: true)
    else
      all
    end
  end
end

# This does not use the counter cache but should since the scope is unchanged
Post.first.comments.filtered(only_approved: false).size
```

So it looks like `Post.comments.size` triggers the counter cache while `Post.comments.all.size` does not. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of how the `counter_cache` works. It needs 2 things:

- Add the `counter_cache: true` to the **belonging** model (Comment)
- Add a column `comments_count` to the **having** model (Post)

The column added to the Post model gets updated everytime you **create or destroy** a model so it will count **all** existing records on the table. This is the reason why it won't work on a scope (a scope might be useful to filter the resulting records, but the actual column `comments_count` is still counting the whole table).

As a workaround I'd suggest you to take a look at and see if it can be used for your usecase https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture.

From their own repo:

```rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  scope :awesomes, ->{ where "products.product_type = ?", 'awesome' }
  scope :suckys, ->{ where "products.product_type = ?", 'sucky' }

  counter_culture :category,
      column_name: proc {|model| "#{model.product_type}_count" },
      column_names: -> { {
          Product.awesomes => :awesome_count,
          Product.suckys => :sucky_count
      } }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that counter cache will not work with scopes however in my example I just want to return the scope unchanged (all). `Post.comments.size` and `Post.comments.all.size` are basically the same but the first one uses the counter cache and the second does not.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to deal with this is to pass the scope to the class method and return it if no additional scope is to be added. It's not as clean but it works. Here is the updated code:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true

  def self.filtered(scope:, only_approved:)
    if only_approved
      scope.where(approved: true)
    else
      scope
    end
  end
end

# This works with counter cache if the scope is returned as is
Comment.filtered(scope: Post.first.comments, only_approved: false).size
```